# Stripes, lines when trying to texture paint

Tags: texture-painting

I am new to blender and I was following a blender guru tutorial. When I got to the texture painting there was a problem that when i was trying to paint on the texture itself - the object was painted in weird stripes. If i was trying to paint on the object - my blender just freezes. I wasn't using any texture masks for the brush. How do I fix this? I hope my explanation was clear...[image]

Here is uv unwrap, i don't think it's supposed to be like that
[image]

Comment: What does your UV Unwrap look like in the UV Editor, and is there some reason you are using a non-square texture for the torus object?

Comment: @CraigDJones Hi. I don't think the `blender-guru` tag is a good idea. A discussion based on a similar idea was discussed [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/should-popular-tutorials-get-their-own-tags). These types of tags are 'meta-tags' (they don't really describe question content) and shouldn't be used, which I briefly mention [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2711/241). Thanks.

Comment: Cool beans. Tag removed,noted. OT: Can we get a better run down of the steps taken prior to this result?

Comment: @CraigDJones I added the pic of uv unwrap. Couldn't screenshot it in full window of uv editor because the file was too big

Comment: Your UV Mapping looks crazy and stretched, overlapped and chaotic. Select all the faces in the object in Edit mode, and try U for Unwrap and select Smart UV Project, and then see what happens when you restart painting.

Comment: @CraigDJones I removed the old map and unwrapped it again. That helped me, thanks!